# Союз (частица) ТАК. В чём отличие от НО и ОДНАКО?

Tags: значение-слов, союзы, частицы

1. — И перестаньте смотреть телевизор.
   — **Так** мы и не смотрим.
2. Хотел вечером прогуляться, **так** дождь пошел.
3. Купил ей шубу, **так** ей все мало.

Comment: Задания временно не выполняются.

Comment: А что не так с этим вопросом?  Слово «так»  – многозначное, в том числе оно может быть союзом. И вот хотелось бы узнать об этой  функции слова, то есть значение и стилевую характеристику.  Участник, задающий вопрос, приводит примеры из обычной бытовой речи, чтобы понять значение союза.  Это никак  не домашнее задание, а грамотно заданный вопрос с  хорошими примерами. Хотелось бы услышать компетентное мнение по поводу закрытия вопроса.

Comment: Эти примеры из задания. Пронумерованы и подшиты. Фразы, сочинённой и проблемной нет, стало быть, не было. «Функцию» можно узнать из словаря.

Comment: Извините, но это вовсе не примеры из задания. А вполне конкретный вопрос. Словарь не дает представление о разнице между "так" и "но", а только указывает на их синонимичность. Прошу дать внятный комментарий.

Comment: Первый пример в Вашем вопросе — это диалог (я его в таком виде и оформила). Если же это повтор чьих-то слов, то необходимо было использовать кавычки — для выделения цитаты.

Comment: Хорошо. Пусть диалог. Но будет ли ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Обождите маленько, *NEO*. Кто знает, может, и не маленько. Пока же я только подправила Ваш вопрос и постаралась сделать так, чтобы его не закрыли.

Answer (score 2):

Интересный вопрос.

"Так" передаёт недовольство, возмущение, употребляется при нарушении планов.
А "но" — звучит нейтрально.